# Qiskit unitary_simulator seems not to be working

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

I'm trying to generate the unitary transformation matrix for a very simple circuit (below):

```
import qiskit as qk
qr = qk.QuantumRegister(1,'q')
cr = qk.ClassicalRegister(1,'c')
qc = qk.QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
qc.initialize([1,0],0)
qc.x(qr)

job = qk.execute(experiments = qc,
                 backend = qk.Aer.get_backend('unitary_simulator'))
result = job.result().get_unitary()
```

But when I try running this code I get the following message after the `qk.execute` command:

```
WARNING:qiskit_aer.backends.aerbackend:Simulation failed and returned the following error message:
ERROR:  [Experiment 0] Circuit circuit-293 contains invalid instructions {"instructions": {save_unitary}} for "statevector" method.Circuit circuit-293 contains invalid parameters  for "statevector" method.
```

This code used to execute ok up to October 2023. Has there been a change in Qiskit in the last few months such that this code is not ok anymore or is it something wrong that I'm doing?

Comment: I don't know the solution, but the problem is with `qc.initialize([1,0],0)`. I also can't access the unitary matrix of quantum circuits which have been initialized.